# Check cloning permissions

Tags: git

How can I programmatically check whether a user is permitted to clone a repo without actually cloning it?

I want something like:
`git-authenticate "$url"`.  It can ask for a password if required and it should return success or failure based on whether or not the authentication succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running `git ls-remote <remote-url>`.  E.g.:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/larsks/sandbox.git
```

If that command is successful, I believe you would be able to clone the repository.